# python-pandas: new column based on index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df similar to the one below:

```
        name    age sex
   1    john    12  m
   2    mary    13  f
   3    joseph  12  m
   4    maria   14  f
```

How can I make a new column based on the index? for example for index 1 and 2, i want them to have the label `1` and for index 3 and 4, i want them to be labeled `2`, like so:

```
        name    age sex label
   1    john    12  m   cluster1
   2    mary    13  f   cluster1
   3    joseph  12  m   cluster2
   4    maria   14  f   cluster2
```

Should i use something like `(df.index.isin([1, 2])) == 'cluster1'`? I think it's not possible to do `df['target'] = (df.index.isin([1, 2])) == 'cluster1` assuming that `label` doesn't exist in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for? You can use lists for different clusters to make your labels arbitrary in this way.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name':['bob','sue','mary','steve'], 'age':[11, 23, 53, 44]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df['label'] = 0
cluster1 = [0, 3]
cluster2 = [1, 2]
df.loc[cluster1, 'label'] = 1
df.loc[cluster2, 'label'] = 2    
#another way
#df.iloc[cluster1, df.columns.get_loc('label')] = 1
#df.iloc[cluster2, df.columns.get_loc('label')] = 2
print(df)
```

output:

```
    name  age
0    bob   11
1    sue   23
2   mary   53
3  steve   44
    name  age  label
0    bob   11      1
1    sue   23      2
2   mary   53      2
3  steve   44      1
```

You can let the initial column creation to be anything. So you can either have it be one of the cluster values (so then you only have to set the other cluster manually instead of both) or you can have it be `None` so you can then easily check after assigning labels that you didn't miss any rows.

If the assignment to clusters is truly arbitrary I don't think you'll be able to automate it much more than this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the solution you are looking for? I doubled the data so you can try different sequences. Here, if you write create_label(df, 3) instead of 2, it will iterate over 3 by 3. It gives you an opportunity to have a parametric solution.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john', 'mary', 'joseph', 'maria', 'john', 'mary', 'joseph', 'maria'],
                   'age': [12, 13, 12, 14, 12, 13, 12, 14],
                   'sex': ['m', 'f','m', 'f', 'm', 'f','m', 'f']})

df.index = df.index + 1

df['label'] = pd.Series()
def create_label(data, each_row):
   i = 0
   j = 1
   while i <= len(data):
      data['label'][i: i + each_row] = 'label' + str(j)
      i += each_row
      j += 1
   return data

df_new = create_label(df, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For small data frame or dataset you can use the below code

```
Label=pd.Series(['cluster1','cluster1','cluster2','cluster2'])
df['label']=Label
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop and use list to get a new column with desired data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
list1 = []
for i in range(len(df.name)):
   if i < 2:
      list1.append('cluster1')
   else:
      list1.append('cluster2')
label = pd.Series(list1)
df['label'] = label
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use iloc and assign the values for the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\+', engine = "python")
df["label"] = "" # adds empty "label" column
df["label"].iloc[0:2] = "cluster1"
df["label"].iloc[2:4] = "cluster2"
```

Since the values do not follow a certain order, as per your comments, you'd have to assign each "cluster" value manually.